# groupmems asks for password for root

Tags: permissions, sudo, password, groups

I have a few scripts that use groupmems to view and modify what users are in a group.
The script runs as root. In Ubuntu 18, it has started to ask for a password, even thou I run as root:

root@ubu18:~# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

```
root@ubu18:~# groupmems -g adm -a uucp
Password:
groupmems: PAM: Authentication failure
```

Try for yourself?

```
docker run -it ubuntu:18.04
root@0e2d06be65c3:/# groupmems -g adm -a uucp
Password:
```

Any idea why? or more important: How make it stop...

Thanks,
/holger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
cat << END > /etc/pam.d/groupmems
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
account         required        pam_permit.so
password        include         system-auth(common-password)
END
```

I guess the 'pam_rootok.so' allows me to modify groups w.o. password as root:

```
root@19..:~# groupmems -g adm -a uucp
root@19..:~# grep adm /etc/group
adm:x:4:uucp
```

thanks to https://wiki.yoctoproject.org/wiki/PAM_Integration#groupmems
for solution